# NullReferenceException excelexport syncfusion grid

Tags: gridview, filter, grid, nullreferenceexception, syncfusion

I am using ASP .Net MVC angular js, syncfusion grid.

This error happens when the grid's datarow is filtered but works if no filter is applied. I need to filter the grid so not filtering it is out of question.

my filter is coded like this:

```
obj.filterColumn("ClientID", "equal", Id_ "and", true);
```

my grid:

```
jQuery("#myGrid").ejGrid({
           dataSource: dataManager,
           columns: cols,
           allowSelection: true,
           enableAltRow: false,
           enableRowHover: true,
           isResponsive: true,
           allowSearching: true,
           selectionSettings: { selectionMode: ["row"] },
           allowFiltering: true,
           allowSorting: true,
           allowScrolling: true,
           allowResizeToFit: true,
           allowPaging: true,
           pageSettings: { pageSize: 12 },
           toolbarSettings: { showToolbar: true, toolbarItems: [ej.Grid.ToolBarItems.ExcelExport] },
           toolbarClick: function (e) {
               this.exportGrid = this["export"];
               if (e.itemName == "Excel Export") {
       
                   this.exportGrid('/MyController/ExportToExcel')
                   e.cancel = true;
               
           },
```

export js:

```
  var gridObj = $("#myGrid").data("ejGrid");
  gridObj.export(url);
```

controller:

```
[System.Web.Http.ActionName("ExcelExport")]
        [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
        public void ExportToExcel()
        {
            string gridModel = HttpContext.Request.Params["GridModel"];
            GridProperties gridProperty = ConvertGridObject(gridModel);

            ExcelExport exp = new ExcelExport();
            var items = _svc.GetItems(someFilters);
            exp.Export(gridProperty, items, "Export.xlsx", ExcelVersion.Excel2010, false, false, "flat-saffron"); //the error i in this line
        }
```

stackTrace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Syncfusion.JavaScript.DataSources.DataOperations.PerformFiltering(IEnumerable dataSource, List`1 filteredColumns) +193
   Syncfusion.JavaScript.DataSources.DataOperations.Execute(IEnumerable dataSource, GridProperties property) +61
   Syncfusion.EJ.Export.GridExcelExport.ExecuteResult(GridProperties GridModel, Object dataSource) +431
   Syncfusion.EJ.Export.GridExcelExport.ExportHelper(GridProperties gridModel, Object dataSource) +777
   Syncfusion.EJ.Export.GridExcelExport.Export(GridProperties gridModel, Object dataSource, Boolean multipleExport) +20
   SwapZilla.Controllers.CollateralPostingController.ExportToExcel() in D:\Dev\MyProject\Controllers\MyController.cs:187
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1.<WrapVoidAction>b__0(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +252
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41() +33
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +76
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +370
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +370
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +184
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +24
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +64
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +607
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +134
```

I am sure that the columns in the grid and datasource of items are the same, and confirmed by the fact that it exports if there gird is not filtered. Also, the have the same rows but I don't think it matters because I tried exporting rows of items with different no of rows than the grid and it exported fine.

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your query and i can't able to reproduce the reported issue. Please find the sample link below

Link: http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/forum/134986/ze/Exporting-743928412

To check please provide the details below,

1. Share the screenshot/ video of the issue that you have faced.
2. Share the Syncfusion Essential studio version details that you are using.
3. Share the columns details that you are using.
4. Share the adaptor details that you are using in grid.
5. If possible please reproduce the issue in the above attached sample